# OSX Yosemite, change the finder folder color

Tags: colors, finder, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to change the ugly light blue of the finder's folders to another one ?

Comment: Do you mean the folder icon?
[This article](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-mac-folder-icon/) shows how you can on a per-folder basis, but not system wide.

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to change all folders icons.